# System.Windows.Forms.Timer in windows server

Tags: c#, windows-services

Could someone please provide me with an example on how to use the System.Windows.Forms.Timer in a windows service. The timer should 'invoke' a non-static windows service method every 10 seconds. I have (unsuccessfully) tried this in my OnStart method:

```
_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(StartProcessingItems);
_timer.Interval = 10000;
_timer.Enabled = true;
_timer.Start();
```

Here StartProcessingItems is my on-static windows service method.

Comment: Why can't you use `System.Timers.Timer`?

Comment: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: It's better to use a `System.Threading.Timer`(or `Timers.Timer`) for a Windows-Service.

Comment: I have tried to use System.Timers.Timer but it only accepts static callbacks as far as I understand ...

Comment: @csetzkorn - That's not correct. It will accept any applicable delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use instead System.Threading.Timer:

```
var t = new Timer(o => 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello from the past! " + (DateTime)o);
}, DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

It will execute the delegate 10s after, and then with a frequency of 1min

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx